# How to solve $y'''=\alpha^3 y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following real, differential equation $$y'''(t)=\alpha^3 y(t),$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant, I have the following solution $$y(t)=Ae^{\alpha t}+Be^{-\alpha t/2}\cos{\omega t} +Ce^{-\alpha t/2}\sin{\omega t},$$ for constants $A, B$ and $C$, and $\omega=\sqrt{3}\alpha/2$. How is this solution derived?

Comment: ODE's with constant coefficients are discussed in any book on ODE. If you couldn't get this particualr  answer you should show your work.

Comment: Well, I would guess the solution $Ae^{\alpha t}$, for some constant $A$. This is a solution, but apparently not the entire one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, whose characteristic equation is

$ m^3 - \alpha^3 = 0 $

This factors into

$(m - \alpha) (m^2 + \alpha m + \alpha^2) = 0 $

So its roots are $ \alpha , \dfrac{1}{2} ( - \alpha \pm i \sqrt{3} \alpha ) $

From this, the solution of the given homogenous equation is

$ y(t) = C_1 e^{\alpha t} + e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2} } \left( C_2 \cos(\omega t) + C_3 \sin( \omega t) \right) $

where $\omega = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \alpha $

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it correct that $C_3$ is a complex constant?

Comment: No, $C_2 $ and $ C_3$ are real.

Comment: Disregarding $C_1 e^{\alpha t}$ term, I have, for $B$ and $C$ real, $$B e^{(-\frac{\alpha}{2}+i\omega) t}+C e^{(-\frac{\alpha}{2}-i\omega) t}=e^{(-\frac{\alpha}{2})}(Be^{i\omega t}+Ce^{-i\omega t}).$$ The last parenthesis, using Euler's formula, simplifies to 

$$(B+C)\cos{(\omega t)}+i(B-C)\sin{(\omega t)},$$
and so it seems $C_3$ is complex.